Strange issue with Async - Await function and LINQ
I have this method:
public async Task<ApiResult> GetListAsync(int? pageNumber, int? pageSize)
{
    ....
    return new ApiResult
    {
        Success = true,
        Data = socios.Select(async t => await GetSocioAsync(baseUrl, endpoint, t))
    };
}

On the other hand, I have this other:
private static async Task<SocioInfo> GetSocioAsync(string baseUrl, string endpoint, Socio t)
{
    return GetSocio(t, (await RestConnection.GetAsync<ApiResult>(baseUrl, string.Format(endpoint, t.ExtPersonaId)))?.Data.ToObject<PersonaInfo>());
}

And finally:
private static SocioInfo GetSocio(Socio t, PersonaInfo? p)
{

}

I expected that Data property in the first code snippet to be of IEnumerable<SocioInfo>  type, however, it is of IEnumerable<Task<SocioInfo>> type.
I think the problem is in GetSocioAsync method.
How can I do it?
